# Foxpro/SQL copy values from cursor to table where id's match

Tags: sql, insert, foxpro

I have a Excel document with a ID column and a [Memo type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) column. (I've made a cursor named Sheet01)
I also have a table named Caption with a ID column, [Memo type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) column and a Code (char).

I need to insert the values of the Memo column from document into the table and assign a existent column a value of my choice (in this case 'DE').

The ID column in the cursor Sheet01 has all numers like this: 28.00000000 (from 1 to ~ 1200)
While the Caption table has like this: 28

This is my best try but obviously it does not work. Help!

```
INSERT INTO captions2(captionid, caption, code) 
SELECT captionid, <caption from the colum 'Header'>, 'DE' FROM Sheet01 WHERE c2.Captionid = Sheet01.Captionid
```

Sample picture:

[http://i.imgur.com/4ugkR7v.png](https://i.imgur.com/4ugkR7v.png)

How do I get the data from excel to cursor? I have a function for that but is similar to APPEND FROM or any other way.

Comment: You are referring to the "c2" alias, but that is nowhere in the query..  It might be easier too if you could edit your question, and post some sample data of the 3 tables (Sheet01 cursor, Captions2 ) and what you expect the results to do...  It should be easy once we see the actual samples.

Comment: How are you getting the data from Excel into the cursor?

Comment: Right you are DRapp, edited the name and added a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT statement isn't correct. Try joining the tables like below.

```
INSERT INTO captions2(captionid, caption, code) 
SELECT  s.captionid, c.caption, "DE"
FROM sheet01 s INNER JOIN captions2 c
    ON s.captionid = c.captionid
```

Comment: Ah, simple as that, totally forgot about JOIN.